# Hide / customize cursor during HTML5 drag

Tags: jquery, css, html, drag-and-drop

I'd like to customize the mouse cursor during a HTML5 drag operation because it's one thing to setDragImage to something representing the object being dragged (not in IE) but it generally looks pretty awful having the standard mouse cursor superimposed. This is especially the case when the 'DragImage' is small and there is no way to control the opacity of the 'DragImage'.

I have various CSS cursors specified on the drop target but these get disabled / ignored by both Chrome and Firefox during a drag. This leaves us with the standard unattractive arrow-and-dotted-box.

Here's the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/MCAU/wect6xuy/8/**

Here's the HTML:

```
<img draggable id="i" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/64/Diy-Paint-Bucket-icon.png"/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">Copy</td>
        <td class="b">None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="c">Move</td>
        <td class="d">Crosshair</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
td {
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: arial;
    border: 3px solid white;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.a {    cursor: copy;}
.b {    cursor: none;}
.c {    cursor: move;}
.d {    cursor: crosshair;}

img {
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
}
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
var i = $('#i');

i.on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'foo');
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this, this.offsetWidth/2, this.offsetHeight/2);
});

$('td').on('dragenter, dragover', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$('td').on('drop', function(e) {
    $(this).append(i);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there a way to hide or change the mouse cursor during a HTML5 drag?

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same problem. I found a working solution with a helper.

Here's the script:

```
$('#i').draggable({
  helper: function(e) {
    return '<img id="drag" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons8/windows-8/64/Diy-Paint-Bucket-icon.png">';
  }
});
```

And this has to be added to your css...

```
#drag {cursor: none;}
```

See the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wect6xuy/31/

**Please note** that I added jQuery UI to the libraries. It's the only way I got it running.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks - that's a nice look! But I am not interested in using jQuery UI, which is why I mentioned HTML5. (I need to be able to drag from one browser window to another, amongst other things.)