# How To hide cursor when dragging using JavaScript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, hide

I need to hide the cursor when dragging on the web browser. It's doesn't have to be an HTML element. If I click anywhere on the page and click and drag, the cursor should be hidden. When dragging finished cursor should be shown again. The cursor can't be hide when I click on the other buttons on the page. It should only be hidden when click and drag not when clicked. Is there any way I can achieve this using CSS and JavaScript? Thanks for your help.

Comment: see: [drag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/drag_event), [dragend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragend_event), and [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: you might want to take a glace at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/31829975/15777388

Comment: i dont know if it will answer your question, buts its worth a shot.

Comment: @JSman225 I have seen it before, but it's exactly not what I need. It also included jQuery

Comment: You can hide the cursor by css `cursor: none;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is just use [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) event

```js
var dragElement = null;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e =>
{
  const isDragging = e.buttons == 1 && (e.movementX || e.movementY);
  document.body.classList.toggle("drag", isDragging);
  if (isDragging)
  {
    if (!dragElement)
      dragElement = e.target;

    console.log("dragging", dragElement);
  }
  else
  {
    dragElement = null;
  }
});
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body.drag
{
  cursor: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#test
{
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

However this method will trigger "dragging" even if user clicked outside of the page.
To solve this, we can track `mousedown` and `mouseup` events:

```js
var dragElement = null;
document.addEventListener("mousedown", e =>
{
  dragElement = e.target;
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", e =>
{
  dragElement = null;
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", e =>
{
  const isDragging = dragElement && (e.movementX || e.movementY);
  document.body.classList.toggle("drag", isDragging);
  if (isDragging)
  {
    console.log("dragging", dragElement);
  }
});

document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
```

```css
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body.drag
{
  cursor: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#test
{
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: pink;
}

canvas
{
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly on the body of the page, but there is a little problem, I'm working with three js library and the canvas is autogenerated by the javascript, so it doesn't work when I click and drag on that canvas. Can you tell me how to do this for a canvas as well? I tried but not working

Comment: It works fine with `canvas` element that was added via javascript, as you can see in second example. So there must be something else in your code that changes cursor.

Comment: doesnt work with elements that have the `draggable` attribute